# Parallelising big CSV file process

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocess

EDIT: Solution
I first split my files into 10000 lines ones using the `split` bash function.
Then:

```
with Pool(processes=32) as pool:
    for level in range(75):
        all_results=[]
        for f in level_dir:
            res = pool.apply_async(process_file, args=[f, level]
            all_results.append(res)
        for res in all_results:
            res.get()
        save_matrix()
```

I'm working with several really big CSV files (74 of them, 10GB to 65GB), and need to read them line by line to extract data from it and put it in a matrix.

I'm using Python, as parsing CSV files with empty fields as well as JSON fields is not that easy using C/C++.

What I'm doing right now is that I use a ThreadPool, but it doesn't look like it uses the CPU to its full capacity (Xeon E5), and I think it may be because of the matrix filling.

```
M = np.zeros((users.size, levels.size, 2))

def process_line(row):
    data    = json.loads(row[3])
    usr     = data['usr']
    #compute stuff
    M[usr, level, 0] = score
    M[usr, level, 1] = t_len

def main():
    for level in range(75):
        csv_f  = open("level{}.csv".format(level))
        reader = csv.reader(csv_f)
        t      = ThreadPool(processes=32)
        for row in reader:
            t.map(process_line, (row, level, ))
        t.join()
        t.close()
    np.save("matrix.npy", M)
```

When I print time stamps at every line process, it looks like changing the number of processes doesn't change anything, it's as slow as when not using ThreadPool.

What can I do to make my code run faster ?

If I keep doing it like this it's literally going to take 3 months to complete.

Comment: Have you measured how much time you spend doing I/O vs time spent on CPU computation (disk I/O is quite sequential, so if that's your bottleneck, your code might not be able to do much)

Comment: You should distribute the files to different processes rather than lines of files

Comment: and you should use multiprocessing, not multithreading

Comment: @BlackBear how can i do so ? Every time I've tried i've had weird terminal glitches, I think it may be due to the fact that all processes access the same matrix ?

Comment: @mad_ using the split bash function i've put my data in files of 10000 lines, yet it still doesn't parallelise. See edit

Comment: Profile it.  Where are the majority of time spent in a single thread?

Comment: @Spoutnovitch parallelism line by line is not going to lead you anywhere. Now you should open every file with pandas and try to vectorialize your row extraction. The last process could easily be parallelized. I suspect that 10000 lines it's kind of small. Could you produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I've done it with 10000 lines files and 32 processes, works like a charm, thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

You can start using `pandas` opening everyfile as `df = pd.read_csv("level{}.csv".format(level))` and then select the columns (let says `col1`, `col2`, ...) and extract the values matrix via `mat = df[["col1", "col2"]].values`

Given the size of your files I suggest you to use `dask.dataframe` to process every single file and save the matrix on a nice format. You then can process the matrix using `dask.array`